# 3 dimensional data presentation with missing datapoints

Tags: plotting, data

from a simulation i have a 3 dimensional dataset in the form {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}. Now i want to plot these datapoints using ListPlot3d for example. I do not want to interpolate between the datapoints! The Problem is that areas with no dataspoints are plottet anyway.

```
data={{0.005,2.5,2.17859},{0.005,2.7,3.29422},{0.005,2.9,4.18894},{0.005,3.1,4.94474},{0.005,3.3,5.58497},{0.005,3.5,6.12328},{0.0052,2.5,2.82223},{0.0052,2.7,3.86527},{0.0052,2.9,4.72697},{0.0052,3.1,5.44918},{0.0052,3.3,6.04614},{0.0052,3.5,6.55115},{0.0054,2.5,3.44993},{0.0054,2.7,4.44714},{0.0054,2.9,5.26443},{0.0054,3.1,5.93569},{0.0054,3.3,6.4982},{0.0054,3.5,6.96563},{0.0056,2.7,5.01079},{0.0056,2.9,5.77741},{0.0056,3.1,6.39913},{0.0056,3.3,6.9346},{0.0056,3.5,7.37356},{0.0058,2.5,4.67146},{0.0058,2.7,5.56134},{0.0058,2.9,6.28327},{0.0058,3.1,6.85945},{0.0058,3.3,7.35591},{0.0058,3.5,7.76783},{0.006,2.5,5.26045},{0.006,2.7,6.09937},{0.006,2.9,6.76066},{0.006,3.1,7.30496},{0.006,3.3,7.76015},{0.006,3.5,8.15299},{0.0062,2.5,5.83747},{0.0062,2.7,6.60495},{0.0062,2.9,7.22496},{0.0062,3.1,7.7294},{0.0062,3.3,8.15356},{0.0062,3.5,8.52506},{0.0064,2.5,6.39799},{0.0064,2.7,7.11053},{0.0064,2.9,7.69154},{0.0064,3.1,8.15527},{0.0064,3.3,8.541},{0.0064,3.5,8.88887},{0.0066,2.5,6.94001},{0.0066,2.7,7.60756},{0.0066,2.9,8.13278},{0.0066,3.1,8.55552},{0.0066,3.3,8.92445},{0.0066,3.5,9.23019},{0.0068,2.5,7.47377},{0.0068,2.7,8.06987},{0.0068,3.1,8.96118},{0.0068,3.3,9.28883},{0.0068,3.5,9.57607},{0.007,2.5,7.98162},{0.007,2.7,8.53929},{0.007,2.9,8.96601},{0.007,3.1,9.34178},{0.007,3.3,9.64951},{0.007,3.5,9.89291},{0.004,3,1.84467},{0.0042,2.6,0.360109},{0.0042,2.8,1.41482},{0.0042,3,2.41145},{0.0044,2.4,0.998343},{0.0044,2.6,0.87138},{0.0044,2.8,2.01633},{0.0044,3,2.97738},{0.0046,2.2,2.13105},{0.0046,2.4,0.378328},{0.0046,2.6,1.50364},{0.0046,2.8,2.61101},{0.0046,3,3.51484},{0.0048,2,3.7272},{0.0048,2.2,1.3613},{0.0048,2.4,0.878496},{0.0048,2.6,2.13361},{0.0048,2.8,3.19259},{0.0048,3,4.06767},{0.005,2,2.83163},{0.005,2.2,0.694599},{0.005,2.4,1.55004},{0.005,2.6,2.76217},{0.005,2.8,3.75311},{0.005,3,4.60029},{0.0052,2,2.02031},{0.0052,2.2,0.853445},{0.0052,2.4,2.21617},{0.0052,2.6,3.3688},{0.0052,2.8,4.32188},{0.0052,3,5.10558},{0.0054,2,1.29896},{0.0054,2.2,1.49253},{0.0054,2.4,2.86949},{0.0054,2.6,3.97373},{0.0054,2.8,4.86902},{0.0054,3,5.60718},{0.0056,2,0.91892},{0.0056,2.2,2.22357},{0.0056,2.4,3.51484},{0.0056,2.6,4.5704},{0.0056,2.8,5.42015},{0.0056,3,6.10564},{0.0058,2,1.44044},{0.0058,2.2,2.91988},{0.0058,2.4,4.14681},{0.0058,2.6,5.14629},{0.0058,2.8,5.92999},{0.0058,3,6.57278},{0.006,2,2.11568},{0.006,2.2,3.60964},{0.006,2.4,4.77195},{0.006,2.6,5.69827},{0.006,2.8,6.44696},{0.006,3,7.04164},{0.0048,2,3.7272},{0.005,1.9,4.29313},{0.005,2,2.83163},{0.0052,1.8,5.01847},{0.0052,1.9,3.35941},{0.0052,2,2.02031},{0.0054,1.7,5.97469},{0.0054,1.8,4.03038},{0.0054,1.9,2.49515},{0.0054,2,1.29896},{0.0056,1.6,7.23521},{0.0056,1.7,4.88952},{0.0056,1.8,3.11004},{0.0056,1.9,1.72853},{0.0056,2,0.91892},{0.0058,1.6,6.05923},{0.0058,1.7,3.90655},{0.0058,1.8,2.28477},{0.0058,1.9,1.09399},{0.0058,2,1.44044},{0.006,1.5,7.63176},{0.006,1.6,4.95186},{0.006,1.7,2.98507},{0.006,1.8,1.57253},{0.006,1.9,1.42393},{0.006,2,2.11568},{0.0062,1.5,6.37579},{0.0062,1.6,3.93074},{0.0062,1.7,2.18144},{0.0062,1.8,1.44613},{0.0062,1.9,2.09063},{0.0062,2,2.87604},{0.0064,1.5,5.21774},{0.0064,1.6,3.00755},{0.0064,1.7,1.55374},{0.0064,1.8,2.07269},{0.0064,1.9,2.80117},{0.0064,2,3.64237},{0.0066,1.5,4.14823},{0.0066,1.6,2.22556},{0.0066,1.7,2.04764},{0.0066,1.8,2.76672},{0.0066,1.9,3.60593},{0.0066,2,4.37796},{0.0068,1.5,3.21053},{0.0068,1.6,2.05988},{0.0068,1.7,2.78893},{0.0068,1.8,3.52765},{0.0068,1.9,4.39647},{0.0068,2,5.10558},{0.007,1.5,2.38498},{0.007,1.6,2.77754},{0.007,1.7,3.49662},{0.007,1.8,4.36857},{0.007,1.9,5.15512},{0.007,2,5.80502}};

 ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction->"Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom,FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.9]},PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 20}}]
```

[image: listplot3d of data]

As you see there are long,straight bars to the side of the plot. In these areas there are no data points. Is there a possiblity to remove those bars? One possibility would be to add some zero values at the points without data... (ListDensityPlot has the same problem). Has someone an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `Histogram3D`?

Comment: I tried this. My data has the form {x,y,z}. To use Histogramm3d I have to convert the data into multiple {x,y}..

Comment: And you don't want `ListPointPlot3D` I assume?

Comment: `ListPointPlot3d` with bars so to say

Comment: Use `Filling -> Bottom` in `ListPointPlot3D`. I don't know any function which does what you want automatically. You'll have to work for it.

Answer (score 6):

I would build the graphics out of [`Cuboid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cuboid.html) objects manually.

It is also possible to abuse [`Histogram3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html) to handle already binned data by constructing a [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object and setting the bin sizes manually.

```
Histogram3D[
 WeightedData[
  data[[All, {1, 2}]],
  data[[All, 3]]
  ],
 {{0.0002}, {0.1}},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try to do it this way. (There are some multiples datapoints in `data`)

Comment: @PhilippHeil What do you want to show when there are multiple points?  Bars would overlap.  Use `GroupBy` to combine the duplicate points in a way appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Just `data2=DeleteDuplicates[data]` so that there are no more duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workarround: I made an array out of the data and added `None` where there is no data.

```
ybins = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 1]]]];
xbins = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]]];
ny = Length[ybins];
nx = Length[xbins];
nyi = Table[Count[data[[All, 1]], ybins[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[ybins]}];
nxi = Table[Count[data[[All, 2]], xbins[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[xbins]}];
posx[i_] := Position[xbins, data[[i, 2]]][[1, 1]]
posy[i_] := Position[ybins, data[[i, 1]]][[1, 1]]
novalues = Table[None, {x, 1, nx}, {y, 1, ny}];
Export["novalues.txt", novalues, "Table"];

Do[novalues = Import["novalues.txt", "Table"];
novalues2 = ReplacePart[novalues, {posx[i], posy[i]} -> data[[i, 3]]];
Export["novalues.txt", novalues2, "Table"], {i, 1, Length[data], 1}];
arraytab = Import["novalues.txt", "Table"];
ListPlot3D[arraytab, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom, 
FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.9]}, PlotRange -> {0.1, 10}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: `Missing[]` is the more conventional symbol used for the absence of data.